# Properties inherited by $f\circ g$ from $f$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

**Prop:** Suppose $g$ and $f \circ g$ are **______**, and $g$ achieves every value in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is **______**.

If in the blanks we put the word "differentiable", the proposition is false. (This is exercise 10-17 in Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th ed.) A counterexample is $f:x\mapsto |x|$, $g:x\mapsto \left(\frac{x}{|x|}\right) x^2$.

If in the blanks we put the word "continuous", I propose that the statement is true. I will place my proof below the fold.

What about if we put in other words, such as "analytic", or "$C^\infty$"?

---

**Prop:** Suppose $g$ and $f \circ g$ are continuous, and $g$ achieves every value in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous.

**Proof**: Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is discontinuous at $\alpha$. Then one of the following cases must obtain:

*Case A:* $\lim_{x\to \alpha^+} f(x) \not\exists$ or $\lim_{x\to \alpha^+} f(x) \neq f(\alpha)$.

*Case B:* $\lim_{x\to \alpha^-} f(x) \not\exists$ or $\lim_{x\to \alpha^-} f(x) \neq f(\alpha)$.

Take a point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ where $g(x) \neq \alpha$, and without loss of generality suppose that $g(x)<\alpha$ and that there exists a $y>x$ such that $g(y)>\alpha$. Let $a:=\inf\{z>x: g(z)>\alpha\}$, and let $b:=\inf\{z>x:g(z)\geq \alpha\}$. I claim that $f\circ g$ will be discontinuous at $a$ if case A obtains, and that $f\circ g$ will be discontinuous at $b$ if case B obtains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claims are false for "analytic" and "smooth".
If $g(x)=x^3$ and $f(x)=x^{1/3}$, then $f\circ g$ is the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Other properties for which this true include "odd", "unbounded" and "one-to-one".